# Unexpected Behavior using Dates in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class DateCalendarTest  {     
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        private final DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");    
        String batchdt = "2015/09/23";
        System.out.println("Date & Calendar Test: " + batchdt);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date1 = df1.parse(batchdt);
        cal.setTime(date1);
        System.out.println("Date & Calendar Test: " + cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Date Calendar Test: 2015/09/23
Date Calendar Test: Mon Nov 09 00:00:00 EST 190
```

Can someone please explain why this behaves in this manner?

Comment: How did you expect it to behave, and why? (Hint: compare the format you've specified with the text you're parsing...)

Comment: the second output is the default format.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As it stands your question is very difficult to answer. Please provide information on what exactly you are having trouble with.

Comment: So, what's the question? You are getting date alright it seems. If you mean the `00:00:00` part, then you should use a `TimeStamp` object rather than Date.

Comment: Date/Calendar is simply a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, they have no concept of format beyond system default, which is generally used for debugging, and you should use a DateFor at of you're choosing to format the result the way you want

Comment: I guess I was expecting the class to interpret the date, then reformat to the other format. Thanks for the comments all!

Answer (score 1):

Your intended data doesn't match the format specified in your `SimpleDateFormat`.  However, by default, it is *lenient* in how it parses the data.  For example, September 31st would be interpreted as October 1st.

Here, it's interpreted as day 9 of month 2,015 of year 23.  2,015 months is 167 years, 11 months, which when added to the year 23 yields the year 190.  In this case, it is very lenient.

The output format is what is expected when printing out a `Date` directly.